# Selenium: Can't click on a button within an iframe

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I load a page with selenium: http://www.legorafi.fr/
Next I try to click on "Tout Accepter" button but even with the css selector it doesn't work. It is for the cookies.

I tried something like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('').click()
```

This is the blue button with text "Tout Accepter"

[image]

How can I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element <kbd>Tout Accepter</kbd> is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('http://www.legorafi.fr/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div#appconsent>iframe")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.button--filled>span.baseText"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('http://www.legorafi.fr/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//div[@id='appconsent']/iframe")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class, 'button--filled')]/span[contains(@class, 'baseText')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: legorafi]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)

Answer (score 1):

The element is present inside an `iframe` you need to switch the `iframe` in order to access the element.

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`() and following css selector

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() and following xpath

```
driver.get("http://www.legorafi.fr/")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#appconsent>iframe")))
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[text()='Tout Accepter']"))).click()
```

You need to import below libraries

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

First switch to the banner frame, then click the accept button:

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = "http://www.legorafi.fr/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
driver.switch_to.frame(2)
button = "/html/body/div/div/article/div/aside/section[1]/button"      
driver.find_element_by_xpath(button).click()
```

(I click the button using XPath but that's just personal taste)

Hope it helped!