# Not able to access the element inside the frame using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

I am using selenium for testing the web pages. Now I am testing a webpage contain frame. The structure us following.

```
<frameset title="Application Content">
<frame name="main" src="qweMain.jsp?language=ENG" scrolling="no" title="Main Frame">
#document
<html>
<head> </head>
<body>
<div>
<ou-button img="ico-menu" id="menuButton" usage="toolbar" onclick="main.doClose();main.onTopMenuClick('CI_MAINMENU', event);" title="Menu (Ctrl+Alt+M)" role="button" tabindex="5" aria-label="Menu (Ctrl+Alt+M)" onkeypress="onButtonKeyPress(event)"><svg class="icon-standard-container icon-size-standard icon-toolbar-container icon-size-toolbar" style=""><use xlink:href="ouaf/assets/svgs/ico-menu.svg#icon"></use></svg></ou-button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
</frame>
<noframes>
Browser not supported
</noframes>
</frameset>
```

I am trying to get the menu button.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ou-button[@img='ico-menu']")).click();
```

But I am getting NoSuchElementException is happening. I search for the solution. So I got some ideas for this. Some developers recommend to  switch the frame before access the element. I tried that too.

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("/html/frameset/frame")));
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/frameset/frame")));
```

But still I am getting the same error. Please let some ideas to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The desired element is within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so to interact with the element you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the desired *frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50621712/7429447) for the desired *elementToBeClickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using *cssSelector*:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("frame[name='main'][title='Main Frame']")));
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("ou-button#menuButton[img='ico-menu'][title^='Menu'][aria-label^='Menu']"))).click();
    ```
  - Using *xpath*:

    ```
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//frame[@name='main' and @title='Main Frame']")));
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//ou-button[@id='menuButton' and @img='ico-menu'][starts-with(@title, 'Menu') and starts-with(@aria-label, 'Menu')]"))).click();
    ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Is it possible to switch to an element in a frame without using driver.switchTo().frame(“frameName”) in Selenium Webdriver Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47472200/7429447)
- [Selenium: Can't click on a button within an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64016305/7429447)
- [NoSuchElementException, Selenium unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48472940/7429447)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a click with some javascript or scroll into view of the element.

`var element = _driver.Driver.FindElement(Selector); var jsExecutor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)_driver.Driver; jsExecutor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element); element.Click();`

Or you could try actions to move to element and click

`var myElement = _driver.Driver.FindElement(Selector); var a = new Actions(_driver.Driver); a.MoveToElement(myElement).Click().Perform();`

I'm not sure how these will handle work with an iframe but hope these might be of some help.

Comment: I am not able to get any element. even simple text box. I am getting NoSuchElementException.

Comment: Could it be the element that you are using, is it getting returned results when searching in the DOM? I could be wrong but in past I have had similar elements and when trying to interact I get ElementNotInteractable error instead of NoSuchElement which may suggest it could be the element or xpath itself? It could also be a waiting issue that may require a wait for element to be present on the page. @DVC

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to switch to frame using below code which is having frame name instead of xpath:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("main");
```

And then try to click on desired element using:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ou-button[@img='ico-menu']")).click();
```

You can switch back to your main window with below code:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```