# How to close the promotion popup in makemytrip.com using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am not able to close the below window on https://www.makemytrip.com/ website:

[image]

I tried with `alert`, `notification` and child browser popup, but nothing had worked out.

Please anyone help on this?

Comment: This ad is only shown once and then saved in cookies. You can save the cookies in your webdriver and that's it, you take it out the first time.

Answer (score 1):

The object(close button) you should have hit to close the pop up is inside another frame.

[image]

So switch to that iframe first and then try to hit the close button. See below the code to switch frame.
**driver.switchTo().frame("id of the element");**

Comment: I am able to handle the popup by switching to frame.
Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

To click on the element <kbd>X</kbd> as the desired element is within a [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the desired *frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50621712/7429447) for the desired *elementToBeClickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):
- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
   driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/");
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe[title^='notification-frame']")));
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("i.we_close"))).click();
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/");
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@title, 'notification-frame')]")));
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//i[@class='wewidgeticon we_close']"))).click();
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: mmt]

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Is it possible to switch to an element in a frame without using driver.switchTo().frame(“frameName”) in Selenium Webdriver Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47472200/7429447)
- [Selenium: Can't click on a button within an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64016305/7429447)

Answer (score 0):

```
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    // Switch to the notification iframe
    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@title, 'notification-frame')]")));

    // Wait for the close button to be clickable
    Thread.sleep(12000);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//i[@class='wewidgeticon we_close']")).click();

    // Switch back to the default content
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).