# How to handle No thanks button within sign in popup accessing Google Home page using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, iframe, webdriverwait

I am a beginner in automation tetsing,when I tried to run the below code, chrome got launched successfully but getting sign in pop up

```
public class Locators { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\Chrome\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(4000));
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"input\"]")).sendKeys("selenium tutorial");
    }
}
```

Popup image:

[image: Popup image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to click on <kbd>No thanks</kbd> [button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2inG.png) which is within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the desired *frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50621712/7429447) for the desired *elementToBeClickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.google.com");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5)).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@src, 'https://ogs.google.com/widget/callout')]")));
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@aria-label='No thanks']"))).click();
  driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("q"))).sendKeys("Diksha Rewatkar");
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: clickNoThanks]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Is it possible to switch to an element in a frame without using driver.switchTo().frame(“frameName”) in Selenium Webdriver Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47472200/7429447)
- [Selenium: Can't click on a button within an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64016305/7429447)