# Select and click link in html element in Selenium Java when iframe tag is absent

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, chropath

I am trying to select and click a link on a web webpage using Selenium. The url is this [test site](https://netbanking.hdfcbank.com/netbanking/). When I used regular element locator or xpath or cssSelectors:

```
//div[@class="welcmewrap"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/span[2][contains(text(), "Know More...")]
```

The chropath showed the message:

> It might be child of svg/pseudo element/comment/iframe from different src. Currently ChroPath doesn't support for them.

Similarly, running the methods on selenium as below:

```
WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("https://netbanking.hdfcbank.com/netbanking/");

//method 1  
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='lightbluecolor'][contains(text(), 'Know More...')]"));

//method 2  
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class=\"welcmewrap\"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/span[@class= ‘lightbluecolor’] [contains(text(), \"Know More...\")]")).click();

System.out.println("know more click");
```

...returned:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //span[@class='lightbluecolor'][contains(text(), 'Know More...')]

When I investigated further, it appears to be a nested frame issue but I couldn't find an "iframe" tag on the webpage source.

How to reach that element?

Answer (score 0):

The element with text as *Know More* on the [HDFC Bank NetBanking](https://netbanking.hdfcbank.com/netbanking/) landing page is within a [`<frame>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447).

---

### Solution

To click on the element with text as ***Know More*** you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the desired *frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50621712/7429447) for the desired *elementToBeClickable*.
- You can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get("https://netbanking.hdfcbank.com/netbanking/");
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//frame[@name='login_page']")));
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: KnowMore]

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Is it possible to switch to an element in a frame without using driver.switchTo().frame(“frameName”) in Selenium Webdriver Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47472200/7429447)
- [Selenium: Can't click on a button within an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64016305/7429447)

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriver driver;
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
        driver=new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        //Actions class method to drag and drop
        //driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://netbanking.hdfcbank.com/netbanking/");
        driver.switchTo().frame("login_page");
        WebElement frame = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Know')])[2]"));
        frame.click();

This know more webelement is present inside the frame so we need to switch to that frame then click on know more link
```